# Error when unpacking dictionary from csv in python

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I'm making a program which talks to you and learns how to respond to phrases. The dictionary responses contains inputs and outputs for the program and I am using csv to store the dictionary externally. When I try to open the dictionary it comes up with: ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack
Here is the code:

```
import csv
import sys


def end():
    w = csv.writer(open("dictionary.csv", "w"))
    for key, val in responses.items():
        w.writerow([key, val])

def process(x):
    x=x.lower()
    if x in responses:
        print(responses[x].capitalize())
    elif x=="exit":
        end()
        sys.exit()
    else:
        add=input("Sorry, I don't know how to respond. What would be a good response?\n")
        responses[x]=add
        end()

responses = {}
n=csv.reader(open("dictionary.csv"))
for key, val in n:
    responses[key] = val
while 1==1:
    process(input("Question:\n"))
```

Can anyone help me with why the error or with the whole program in general? I'm trying to recreate simple machine learning on python.

Any help appreciated.
Thanks.

Mitra0000

Comment: For some reason csv is saving a blank row in between each dictionary entry. The csv file looks like this when saved.
hi          hello

Comment: any other entries saved have a space between them and the previous one

Comment: would csv.dictreader get rid of the spaces?

Answer (score 1):

Separate answer for a different strategy:

Save yourself the CSV hassle by using JSON. Reading and writing a dict to a JSON file is as simple as:

```
import json

# reading an existing file
with open('dictionary.json') as f:
    responses = json.load(f)

# writing/ overwriting a file
with open('dictionary.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(responses, f, indent=2, sort_keys=True)
```

The keyword arguments aren't necessary but they make it a lot more readable. Then just open it in a text editor.

Comment: Thanks. This solution works perfectly. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works for me. Try debugging it to find where the error is coming in (probably the `for key, val in n` line, but it's good to be sure). How are you initialising the csv file? If you create a new file manually in a text editor, in python, or using `touch`, does it change the behaviour?

Comment: I've found the problem is that the program is saving the dictionary badly. The default program for opening csv files on my computer is excel but every time I run the program and then check the csv file each dictionary entry has been put after a blank row.

Comment: Stop opening it in excel, that could be your problem. I know that LibreOffice doesn't do that, but try opening it in something safe like Notepad++. And just FYI, linespaces don't appear in the comments above.